# Degree of Gauss map coincides with Euler characteristic

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $M^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a compact hypersurface, oriented with the smooth normal vector field $N(X) \perp T_xM$. Let $G: M^n \to S^n$ be the corresponding Gauss map. Does it follow that $\deg(G) = \chi(M)$, the Euler number of $M$?

**Thoughts so far.** A generic point $a \in S^n$ induces a vector field $v_a$ on $M$, by $v_a(x) =$ tangential component of $a$ at $x \in M$. But I am not sure what do from here on out. Could anybody help?

Comment: Try it for the unit sphere. Also, when $n$ is ofd, won't you have a serious problem?

Comment: Ok, I will do like Ted Shifrin, and just give a hint (the same hint basically, with more details, in some sense). What is the Gauss map on $S^3$? What is its degree? What is the Euler characteristic of $S^3$?